# How to change membership status from active to expired after subscription end date in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

After the expiry date i would like to change the subscription status to inactive.
So what is the best way to achieve this.

My Subscription models as follows:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    membership = models.ForeignKey(Membership, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Start Date'), null=True, blank=True)
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Expiry Date'), null=True, blank=True)
    token = models.TextField(_('Token'), max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(_('Active'), default=False)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use celery or something Cron based like django-crontab. Create job that runs every midnight checking expiry date

Comment: you can make a property method instead of active field that returns boolean value depend on comparison of current time and expiry_date field. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-methods

Answer (score 1):

user this method on your model:

```
def check_status(self):
    now = timezone.now()
    if now > self.expiry_date and self.active:
        self.active = False
        self.save()
        return False
    return self.active
```

and in your view when you want to check for subscription status you just check **check_status**:

```
user.subscription.check_status
```